# How to increase the document size of mongodb(More than 16MB)?I

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am not able increase file size more than 16 MB . I don't have option to create more than one document. I read many blogs regarding the same but, I do not got any particular solution. I want to adjust data in single file which is 30 MB in size

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307800/mongodb-single-document-size-limit-is-16mb

Comment: Found [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) after a simple google search.

Comment: I already read that links but I do not got proper solution because i want to use single document only

Answer (score 5):

From the docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents):

> BSON Document Size The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.
>
> The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot
>   use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount
>   of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB
>   provides the GridFS API. See mongofiles and the documentation for your
>   driver for more information about GridFS.

The only question remains: **Are you sure you need a single document that large?**

Comment: then GridFS it is :)

Comment: Is it a 16MB+ BSON document or just a BLOB of binary content like an image or PDF?

Comment: @Fredrik - that is an excellent point! I **assumed** we are talking about pure data but as we all know - assuming is the mother of all fu***dups! you got my vote for that :)

Comment: It is only BSON document.

Comment: I am getting maximum BSON document size exceeds during AEM 6.1 to AEM 6.3 upgrade. Is there any way to resolve.

Comment: The only way seems to compile Mongo yourself run it on your servers(instead to use "cloud" services)

Comment: "The maximum document size helps ensure..." - thanks, we have admins to 'ensure' rules. I'm a new user, is there anything else behind the corner I should watch before I invest significant amount of time in Mongo?

Comment: In short: remember that most of time you store in your db un-indexed data that you are not really using (e.g. making your db a storage solution). The best strategy is to keep only indexed + query-able data at mongo and move the rest to a storage solution (you may also keep storage references as part of your data). If everything is held for queries - please make sure you create proper indexes and that you store your data in a way that ease the load when making queries over it.

Comment: 16 MB that large? Hardware has improved over the last 5 years, data got bigger. What a showstopper.