# Spring + MongoDB - MongoTemplate + Criteria Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot + MongoDB. I need to query database based on some criteria where my methods looks like below:

```
@Override
    public List<MyCollection> findBuyByCriteria(Request request) {
        Query search = new Query();
        search.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ItmId").in(request.getItmIds()));
        return mongoTemplate.find(search, MyCollection.class);
    }
```

Problem that I am facing is:
At line

search.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ItmId").in(request.getItmIds()));

**request.getItmIds has 1 million Ids due to which I am getting an exception**

org.bson.BsonMaximumSizeExceededException: Document size of 46282052 is larger than maximum of 16793600

Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: Where does `request.getItmIds()` come from? Can't it be paged so that you don't send 1 million IDs at once?

Comment: Can't it be paged so that you don't send 1 million IDs at once? - This is exactly where I am stuck .. Can MongoDB query be paginated or something else..

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15307800/2987755

Comment: Also: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: The pagination is a challenge with this approach. There is a possible solution to implement pagination but the tradeoff for that is to make two calls to the database.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Spring Data JPA, you can do something like:
`findBySomeField(String someField)`

If you have a more complex query, you can actually use JPQL and write a custom query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o.* from SomeObject o WHERE :someField IS NULL OR o.someField = :somefield)
public findBySomeField(@Param("someField") String someField);
```

Comment: The question mentions that he is using MongoDB, not JPA.